# Google+ ignores preview images

Tags: google-plus, facebook-opengraph, microdata, schema.org

**Problem**

Google+ ignores the preview images of my website.

**Proposed solutions I tried**

I read some posts about this "possible" problem and tried to implement the proposed solutions but still have no positive results.

- My website contains Schema.org-Microdata in the `head`, generated with
  https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/?hl=en
- I also added opengraph meta tags
- My images are larger than 100px x 120px

**My questions**

It works fine with Facebook but Google+ still ignores my preview images.

Can anybody check the source-code? Maybe I did something wrong :-)

I use one of the new top-level-domains ".photography". Could that be the problem?

**Website**

Here is one example page: http://bavaga.photography/galleries/rome-italy/image/2010-08-12-18-54-19-00001-rome-italy.jpg/

Comment: When I look at the share preview, I see Google trying show an image but it's broken so the markup seems to be working. Maybe Google just has a broken image cached or maybe they are having trouble processing that image for some reason. If you have been changing the markup and testing a lot the G+ snippet might not be current since it's cached.

Comment: Also note that Google+ has been changing how it processes and displays links to websites and their metadata. Things are still shaking out there so a lot of things might be broken while they do.

Comment: Hmm, this looks ok - it renders OK in the rich snippets tool, so may well be a G+ snippet bug: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbavaga.photography%2Fgalleries%2Frome-italy%2Fimage%2F2010-08-12-18-54-19-00001-rome-italy.jpg%2F

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It looks like G+ has problems with the new top-level domains. I tried it with an old style ".com"-Domain and it works fine. Maybe I have to be more patient :-)

Comment: I will try to contact Google and ask them what the problem is or could be! Gona keep you up to date. Wish me luck ;-)

Comment: @bavaga when you say you tried it with a .com, do you mean a .com you own pointing at the same page? Or a different domain and site altogether?

Comment: @abraham my own .com / .de pointing to the same page. I contacted  the Google-Developers. They will invastigate the problem https://plus.google.com/102405264797463587441/posts/ehtfv2FfMEv

Comment: It looks like Google has fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has fixed this problem!